# Cast lambda expression to class object whose constructor accept that lambda (Brief lambda)

Tags: c++, lambda, functional-interface

I am figuring out a way to program a kinda of FunctionalInterface - Java's similar ones - in C++ (although it already provides these features).

I am practicing with Predicate for the moment. Actually I have already done it:

```
namespace _utils{

    namespace _functional{

        template <typename T>
        class Predicate: public FunctionalI{
            protected:
                std::function<bool(T)> predicate;

            public:
                Predicate(std::function<bool(T)> predicate){
                    this->predicate = predicate;
                }

                inline bool test(T t){
                    return this->predicate(t);
                }
        };
    }
}
```

And this is `main.cpp`:

```
bool foo(_functional::Predicate<int> predicate){
    return predicate.test(2);
}

int main(){
    _functional::Predicate<int> tmp = _functional::Predicate<int>([] (int x) ->  bool{ return x == 2; });

    std::cout << foo(tmp);

    return 0;
}
```

Now, of course it works!

My question is about how could I make a brief of that lambda expression? I mean, is there any way to pass "directly" the lambda expression (without give it to the Predicate constructor) and then let it construct the Predicate object with right that lambda expression.

I have taken a look at using aliasing and even at functor with `operator()`, but they did not helped me (maybe I have not been able to do it)

An example of main.cpp which I wish to reach:

```
bool foo(_functional::Predicate<int> predicate){
    return predicate.test(2);
}

int main(){
    // To much stuff to write
    //std::cout<<foo(_functional::Predicate<int>( [] (int x) -> bool{ return x == 2; } ));

    //What I whish to reach
    foo([] (int x) -> bool{return x == 2;} );

    return 0;
}
```

Another question to make a brief of lambda expr is: is there a way to make implicit the return type of lambda and even the keyword `return`?

Comment: `template<typename T> bool foo(T&& t) { return t(2); }`

Comment: CTAD might help.

Comment: @Jarod42 Only if you insist on replicating an API that Java uses because it can't overload operators. The whole `Predicate` class is pointless in C++.

Comment: Unrelated to question: All identifiers starting with an underscore are reserved in the global namespace scope.

Comment: `-> bool` is unneeded, deduced from `return x == 2;`. return cannot be omitted.

Comment: Even if you don't want to use the recommended way of passing the lambda using a template parameter, what is the point of `Predicate`? Isn't it just a limited `std::function`? Wouldn't an alias `template<typename T> using Predicate = std::function<bool(T)>;` be sufficient?

Comment: @PasserBy Oh, thanks! It is working. Now I am gonna studying rvalue reference as you suggested

Comment: @user17732522 I am just practicing with it. Yeah, I was getting more about aliasing indeed. About underscore and namespace, I have just read about it; thanks for that

Comment: @DynoZ if you want to constraint on type, the proper way would *probably* be [concept and constraint](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) (with generic callable) in c++20, or normal sfinae before. Although tbf `std::function` is probably easier to learn, and it has it's use (type-erasure) too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `foo( [] (int x) -> bool{return x == 2;} );` is that it tries to perform two implicit conversions (lambda to `std::function` and `std::function` to `Predicate`). C++ doesn't allow you to do that. Instead, you can state explicitly that you are initialising `Predicate` by adding braces:

```
foo( { [] (int x) -> bool{return x == 2;} } );
//   ^ initialise Predicate object        ^
```

Or create a template constructor as suggested in comments:

```
class Predicate : public FunctionalI {
protected:
    std::function<bool(T)> predicate;

public:
    template <typename PredType>
    Predicate(PredType predicate) : predicate{ std::move(predicate) }
    {
        // use member init list instead of reassigning object in constructor
    }
    // ...
};
```

Comment: std::function cannot be declared unless a previous declaration of template has been provided? At least, 'auto' is expected

Comment: Oh, sorry. I have just figured out my mistake about misunderstanding your answer. Anyway, it helped me, too. Actually, it is just what I was looking for. Thanks!